# What to do when a post appears in multiple places in the Review Queue?

Tags: support, review-queues

I've seen the following behavior several times while going through the review queue.

- A new user comes along and posts a short answer to an old question (usually a comment like I'm facing the same problem).
- I go to the review Queue, and start with the `Late Answers` queue, and find this answer. I flag it.
- I proceed to the `First Posts` queue and see the same post. I skip it, as I have already flagged it.
- I go to the `Low Quality Posts` queue and again find the same post.

What should be done when you see the same post in multiple queues? Wouldn't it be better if the same post is not shown multiple times to the same person?

Comment: This (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153406/posts-come-up-in-multiple-review-queues) says the problem is solved, but I am still seeing the behavior. I saw it just a few minutes back.

Comment: This would be an issue almost sitewide.  (There are some differences in how reviews for the four most popular SE sites are implemented and how the rest are.)  The best thing for you to do is research the status of this on the main meta site and, if it does not appear to be resolved, post your question there.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an issue that no longer occurs at GIS Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

This situation it is not possible anymore for First Posts, Late Answers, and Low Quality review queues.
If one review the post in one of the above 3-cited queues, then, the post automatically disappear from the other.

However, it is still possible to have the same thread on Suggested Edits, Close Votes, and Reopen Votes at the same time and this is status-by-design (e.g. a question can go to the Suggested Edit queue and it goes directly to the Reopen queue).

In this case, the answer to the question is to review them normally.

See this [thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153406/posts-come-up-in-multiple-review-queues?rq=1) and many other related on MSO for reference.

Comment: I recall (non-specifically) that some elements of the SO review process are not carried over into the smaller sites, due to the (vast) differences in amount of reviewing that needs to get done. More information about this should be available on the Meta site.

Comment: I think you are saying that this is no longer an issue for GIS-SE.  Certainly, I review at GIS-SE a lot and am not seeing the problem so will vote to Close this question using the closest option I can find to "no longer an issue".